# Laravel Docker-Compose

Tags: bash, laravel, dockerfile

I've created a repo for some Docker containers that work together with docker-compose to make a very easy and quick installation for Laravel including nginx, mariadb, and redis. Laravel is known for having one somewhat annoying step to get it started, which is that the `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` directories have to be writable by the webserver/php process:

`chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache`

However, docker containers that use shared volumes between the container and host tend to have permission issues because of discrepancies between uids and guids differing between the container and the host.

This is a Mac-only project until I get these basic issues solved. The repository can be found [here](https://github.com/wilkesreid/easy-laravel).

I would greatly appreciate solutions for how to have the PHP process user in the PHP container have write permissions on those directories in the shared volume.

This install script (called by typing `./install` into the terminal) is what should be theoretically setting the permissions:

### install

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "installing and building docker containers..."
docker-compose up -d

echo "installing laravel/installer via composer..."
rm -rf code
if [[ $(composer global show) != *laravel/installer* ]]
  then
    composer global require "laravel/installer"
fi

echo "installing laravel..."
laravel new code

echo "changing working directory to code..."
cd code

echo "setting permissions..."
chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
docker exec ${PWD##*/}_php_1 chgrp -R www-data /code
docker exec ${PWD##*/}_php_1 chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache

echo "installing predis..."
composer require "predis/predis"

echo "installing correct database settings to laravel..."
sed -i '' "s/DB_HOST=127.0.0.1/DB_HOST=mariadb/" .env
sed -i '' "s/DB_DATABASE=homestead/DB_DATABASE=laravel/" .env
sed -i '' "s/DB_USERNAME=homestead/DB_USERNAME=laravel/" .env
sed -i '' "s/REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1/REDIS_HOST=redis/" .env
sed -i '' "s/CACHE_DRIVER=file/CACHE_DRIVER=redis/" .env
sed -i '' "s/SESSION_DRIVER=file/SESSION_DRIVER=redis/" .env

echo "returning working directory to previous state..."
cd ..

echo "installation complete"
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
    networks:
    - front-tier
    - back-tier
  php:
    image: laravel_pdo_php
    build: ./php
    working_dir: /code
    volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    - ./php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    networks:
    - back-tier
    expose:
    - "9000"
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
    - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
    - back-tier
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_USER: laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    expose:
    - "3306"
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
    - back-tier
    expose:
    - "6379"
volumes:
  mariadb:
    driver: local
networks:
  front-tier:
    driver: bridge
  back-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

### php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If any of the commands fail, then the script ploughs blindly on afterwards.  That's probably not what we want - and it's certainly not what we want if this command fails:

> ```
> cd code
> ```

We can fix this by testing the exit status of the command, e.g. with `||`, but I recommend setting the `-e` flag of the shell to make failed commands exit the shell immediately.  While we're at it, let's set `-u` so that misspelling a variable name is caught as an error:

```
set -eu
```

---

We can simplify this `if`/`then`:

> ```
> if [[ $(composer global show) != *laravel/installer* ]]
>   then
>     composer global require "laravel/installer"
> fi
> ```

If we read it as "either `laravel/installer` is already required, else require it", that becomes

```
[[ $(composer global show) == *laravel/installer* ]]  ||
    composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Or we could write it in portable shell, allowing us to use plain `/bin/sh` rather than needing Bash:

```
case "$(composer global show)" in
    *laravel/installer*) ;;  # no action needed
    *) composer global require "laravel/installer" ;;
esac
```

---

Here, we expand a variable unsafely:

> ```
> docker exec ${PWD##*/}_php_1 chgrp -R www-data /code
> docker exec ${PWD##*/}_php_1 chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
> ```

We need quotes, i.e. `"${PWD##*/}_php_1"`.  And we might want to consider running both commands together:

```
docker exec "${PWD##*/}_php_1" \
    sh -c 'chgrp -R www-data /code && chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache'
```

Even in a Docker container, I feel dirty about granting write permission to "other" users (i.e. the 002 bit).

---

As [mentioned by Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ](/a/279896/75307), the multiple `sed` commands modifying one file can be combined.  Also, if we use the keys to address the relevant lines, we can avoid repetition and be more robust about initial values:

```
sed -i '' \
    -e '/^DB_HOST=/s/=.*/=mariadb/' \
    -e '/^DB_DATABASE=/s/=.*/=laravel/' \
    -e '/^DB_USERNAME=/s/=.*/=laravel/' \
    -e '/^REDIS_HOST=/s/=.*/=redis/' \
    -e '/^CACHE_DRIVER=/s/=.*/=redis/' \
    -e '/^SESSION_DRIVER=/s/=.*/=redis/' \
    .env
```

This is still a little tedious to write, so I have previously written a function to create a suitable `sed` script from a list of keys and values (which as written needs Bash for the `${//}` substitution; we don't actually need that here because none of our values contain `/`, so we could get away with `"$@"` instead of `"${@//\//\\/}"`):

```
change_values() {
    printf '/^%s *=/s/=.*/= %s/\n' "${@//\//\\/}"
}
```

```
sed -i '' \
    -e "$(change_values \
              DB_HOST mariadb \
              DB_DATABASE laravel \
              DB_USERNAME laravel \
              REDIS_HOST redis \
              CACHE_DRIVER redis \
              SESSION_DRIVER redis \
       )" \
    .env
```

---

This command is pointless:

> ```
> echo "returning working directory to previous state..."
> cd ..
> ```

The only thing we do in this process after that is a simple `echo`, which is unaffected by the change of directory.  We can simply remove these two lines.

Answer (score 1):

## Permissions issue

> I would greatly appreciate solutions for how to have the PHP process user in the PHP container have write permissions on those directories in the shared volume.

Instead of having a docker container for nginx, my team switched to just using the [built-in PHP webserver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), initiated with the `php artisan serve` command - which was mentioned in [the Laravel 7 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#clipButton-2):

> #### Local Development Server
>
> If you have PHP installed locally and you would
> like to use PHP's built-in development server to serve your
> application, you may use the `serve` Artisan command. This command will
> start a development server at `http://localhost:8000`:
>
> ```
> php artisan serve
> ```
>
> More robust local development options are available via [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead) and
> [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/valet).

Subsequent versions of the documentation appear to mention this command in the [**Your First Laravel Project** section](https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#your-first-laravel-project), though they also mention using [Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/master/sail) in the section [Laravel & Docker](https://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#laravel-and-docker).

When using the local development server there is no need to worry about permissions on the shared directories.

MY IDE, i.e. [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), allows for [Startup tasks to be configured](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2022.2/settings-tools-startup-tasks.html?utm_source=product&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=PS&utm_content=2022.2), and I have a task that runs `php artisan serve --port=8000` so I don't have to manually run it.

## Install script

### Rimraf

The sixth line is:

> ```
> rm -rf code
> ```

Perhaps this is just added to run the script subsequent times, though I would be wary of a script that force removed a directory without prompting me first. it may be wise to check to see if that directory exists before removing it. If it does exist, then perhaps it would be wise to warn the user, possibly even requiring confirmation before removal.

### Repeated `sed` calls

The shell script updates the env file using `sed`:

> ```
> echo "installing correct database settings to laravel..."
> sed -i '' "s/DB_HOST=127.0.0.1/DB_HOST=mariadb/" .env
> sed -i '' "s/DB_DATABASE=homestead/DB_DATABASE=laravel/" .env
> sed -i '' "s/DB_USERNAME=homestead/DB_USERNAME=laravel/" .env
> sed -i '' "s/REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1/REDIS_HOST=redis/" .env
> sed -i '' "s/CACHE_DRIVER=file/CACHE_DRIVER=redis/" .env
> sed -i '' "s/SESSION_DRIVER=file/SESSION_DRIVER=redis/" .env
> ```

As [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/278829/120114) explains the multiple `sed` commands can be combined using the `-e` flag, allowing for reduction of overwriting of files.

```
sed -i '' -e "s/DB_HOST=127.0.0.1/DB_HOST=mariadb/" \
 -e "s/DB_DATABASE=homestead/DB_DATABASE=laravel/" \
 -e "s/DB_USERNAME=homestead/DB_USERNAME=laravel/" \
 -e "s/REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1/REDIS_HOST=redis/" \
 -e "s/CACHE_DRIVER=file/CACHE_DRIVER=redis/" \
 -e "s/SESSION_DRIVER=file/SESSION_DRIVER=redis/" .env
```